# Where to put PNG files and how to refer to them from ImageView in XML layout?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-assets

After reading 2 books on Android programming, I am trying to port an iOS Word game app:

[image: word game screenshot]

I would like to have 2 classes inheriting from `View` - [SmallTile.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/DragAndDraw/src/de/afarber/draganddraw/SmallTile.java) and [BigTile.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/DragAndDraw/src/de/afarber/draganddraw/BigTile.java).

Both classes should be composed of an `ImageView` (id: "image") and 2 `TextViews` (ids: "letter" and "value").

The difference between them is that BigTile will be draggable and its "image" has a shadow.

I have put the graphical assets into the directory [res/drawable-mdpi](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/master/DragAndDraw/res/drawable-mdpi) and I am trying to refer to them from the layout files [res/layout/small_tile.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/DragAndDraw/res/layout/small_tile.xml) and [res/layout/big_tile.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/DragAndDraw/res/layout/big_tile.xml) as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/small_tile.png" >
</ImageView>
```

But I get the error

> No resource found that matches the given name
>   (at 'src' with value '@drawable/small_tile.png')

as you can see in the Eclipse-screenshot (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0cQG.png)):

[image: eclipse screenshot]

I have tried other paths for my assets as well - for example `res/drawables` and `src/assets`.

Also another question: how to load the layout files from a `View`?

There is only an `ImageView` in the [res/layout/small_tile.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/DragAndDraw/res/layout/small_tile.xml) right now, but I'd like to add the two `TextView`s there too (for the letter and its numerical value) - and then load it from the [SmallTile.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/DragAndDraw/src/de/afarber/draganddraw/SmallTile.java).

From the programming books I know how to load a layout from `Activity` or `Fragment` - call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in `onCreate` - but where and what to call in a `View` class?

Comment: it looks like you have other errors in other layout files, fix them so that your resources get generated properly

Comment: No, everything else compiles and runs fine in emulator - when I remove the `src` attribute from the ImageView in small_tile.xml and big_tile.xml. My app is at GitHub - you can see this for yourself: https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/master/DragAndDraw

Comment: this looks like your code is having trouble finding the resource. Could be a clean issue, or perhaps there is a problem in one of your layout / xml files, or maybe one on your resource names has an illegal char in it?

Comment: I have renamed the PNG files again to ensure there are only latin letters in their names. I have issued "refresh" and "clean project" in Eclipse several times and restarted Eclipse as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When referencing Drawables, you only refer to them by their file name. You should omit the extension.

For example, the ImageView you posted should look like this in XML:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/small_tile" >
```

Note the change from `android:src="@drawable/small_tile.png"` to `android:src="@drawable/small_tile"`

To use your custom layout with your View, you will want to create a `LayoutInflater` and call `inflate(R.id.my_layout, this);`. For example:

```
public SmallTile(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view_layout, this);
}
```

Comment: +1 Removing `.png` has helped, thank you. Do you have an advice on how to use small_tile.xml from SmallTile.java (a View-based class)?

Comment: I updated my answer. You might also find [this tutorial](http://trickyandroid.com/protip-inflating-layout-for-your-custom-view/) helpful.

Comment: To use `LayoutInflater.inflate()` I had to change the base class of `SmallTile` from `View` to `ViewGroup`.